# R Programming - Error in sys.call(sys.parent()) : node stack overflow

Tags: r

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
  for(i in id) {

    filenames <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE);

    pollutant_data <- NULL;

    for (f in filenames){
      fdata <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE);
      pollutant_data <- c(pollutant_data,fdata$pollutant);
    }

    poll_mean <- mean(pollutant_data, na.rm=TRUE);

    return(poll_mean);
  }


}

source("pollutantmean.R");
```

When I ran the code shown above, I got the following error message .... 
Error in sys.call(sys.parent()) : node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow

Why am I seeing this error and how do I avoid it?
Thank You!

Comment: The function definition appears to be done in a console session. Then calling source() would be pulling in something from an R file but what is in "pollutantmean.R" is anybody's guess. Just defining a function should not throw that error.

Comment: Are you source()ing a file that has a source() in it? Seems likely you have infinite source()ing going on.

Comment: MrFlick, the error went away after removing the source() line in the file. Thx!